# Opencart Admin Login Disable

Tags: opencart

My have a issue. I want dashboard panel access directly without admin login page.
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0KrlE.png)
How i can solve?

Thanks.

Comment: Seems like a bad idea, why do you want this?

Comment: @Paul.Feakins This requires for my project.

Comment: That is a terrible answer that tells me precisely nothing.

Answer (score 0):

That will require a lot of work to do, so maybe try to think out of the box , instead of removing the login requirement why not just force login without any user input

like so:

```
<script>

    $(document).ready(function() {

      function Login(){
            $("#input-username").val('YOUR ADMIN USERNAME')
            $("#input-password").val('YOUR ADMIN PASSWORD')
            $("form").submit()
        }

        Login();

    });

</script>
```

Since you are giving free access to your admin panel i assume that you do not care about user login and password and might as well show them in the code.

Comment: No, I want access dashboard panel directly.